# Test case run in Intellij is fine but faild in gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

[This test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWDBK.png) passes when I run in IntelliJ:

```java
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

String d1s = "11-Dec-2021";
String d2s = "12-Dec-2021";
Date d1 = formatter.parse(d1s);
Date d2 = formatter.parse(d2s);
```

However, it fails when I change the 'Run tests using:' setting to Gradle from Intellij IDEA.

```
DeleteCommandTest > deleteExpense() FAILED
    java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11-Dec-2021"
        at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java: 395)
        at seedu.duke.command.DeleteCommandTest.deleteExpense(DeleteCommandTest.java:22)
```

How can I solve the problem and why does this happen?

Comment: Can you import the test as code, and not as a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is locale-sensitivity of the month pattern `MMM`. From the API documentation:

> [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner.

While month `12` is `Dec` in the English locale, it is `Dez` in German and `Déc` in French. It seems that IntelliJ and Gradle run with different locale settings. A solution to your problem is to construct `SimpleDateFormat` with the expected locale:

```java
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```